# Collation Problem in asp.net connecting sql

Tags: sql

Hi when I use this query I don't get any result.

In my table I have used collation Macedonian_BIN so the letters are in Macedonian Language.
What I need to do this code to work, it doesn't compare 2 values

For example

НОВ=НОВ

The ed is getting the value HOB I guess the problem is when is comparing the HOB value with the HOB in database

```
select * from Publisher where Motor  like '%" + ed + "%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly add the [COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) keyword to change the default collation as follows:

```
select * from Publisher 
where Motor COLLATE Macedonian_BIN like '%" + ed + "%' ";
```

(substitute your desired collation)

Comment: I dont know why but its not working this way i have tried many times.THNX anyway ;)

Comment: @Betim: could you be more specific? What is some sample data, what do you expect and what are you getting...

Comment: i am making a search query and my data in database are in Macedonian Language so i am taking values from dropdownlist.the values in the dropdownlist are also in Macedonian language.

Comment: @Betim: that's great, but it still doesn't provide an actual example!

Comment: I also try to execute this query in SQL SSMS select * from Publisher where Mark='Aston Martin'; works select * from Publisher where Mark='HBO'; nothing empty

Comment: @Betim: if you fixed it yourself, care to add your solution to your question as a reference for others who might face the same problem??

Comment: The problem was: firstly i just collated some columns thats why it didnt worked, than i collated all the database and it worked but the problem was the database didnt allowed me to callate it because it was multiuser than i made it single user i changet the language of database and than i made it multiuser again and it worked.So the problem was in the collated columns,you can show the language in those columns it shows the charachters but makes problem in connection (that was in my case)